# How can I stop Windows from providing warnings about my processor?

Tags: windows-7

Windows is notifying me every 20 minutes that my processor (i7 7700k) isn't supported by Windows 7, yet according to Intel it is. This wouldn't have been an issue if the message appeared once a month, or even once a week, but the problem is that the message is appearing every 20 minutes or so. This is especially annoying when I work in Photoshop and my selection gets cleared right when the window switches to the warning.

[image]

Originally I tried uninstalling the update causing the issue (KB4012218), which didn't work as it installed itself again, and so I fixed it by only selecting to install important security updates, which worked for about a week or two, but then yesterday one "security update called "April 2017 Security Quality Update for Windows (KB4015546)" showed up in Windows Update again and unlike ALL the other security updates, the checkmark was checked and grayed out, so I couldn't uncheck it, and the "hide update" was grayed out as well. I installed it in an attempt to uninstall it, and after I restarted the computer, it said said "Configuring Windows Updates" and then into a really weird screen - it was the normal Windows 7 boot animation, but instead of "Starting Windows" it said "Applying registry operation 3/40 (HKEY/current)" and then "Applying update operation 2/5 (C/Windows/Syste...)", and at first I thought I may have accidentally made it upgrade to Windows 10, but luckily not. The computer boot up and the annoying pop-up appeared. After that was done I thought the problem could've been fixed by uninstalling the update that caused the problem, but even though the update was uninstalled, the issue still remained.

I don't understand why this is considered to be a security update, as this update blocks any and all installation of Windows Update, including important security updates. Was there recently a virus discovered that made the i7700k vulnerable to remote executions?

I reinstalled Windows 7 and after hours of investigation, I found out that another update was causing the check mark grey out of the "security update" was another update, one of the updates that gets installed with all the other thousands of updates.

The strange thing is is that Intel actually fully supports the Intel i7 7700k on Windows 7. Both the chipset and graphics driver is available for it, and does offer much better performance then the previous processor I had installed according to SiSoft.

I understand that Microsoft wants people to be using an OS built for the specific processor, and I appreciate that Microsoft is notifying me, but I would like a way to unsubscribe for these warnings and take the risks, as according to Intel, the i7-700k processor fully supports Windows 7. I called and confirmed with Intel and they confirmed that I should have no problem running Windows 7 on it. I think Microsoft made a mistake by confusing the arm-based Intel Stratix 10 with Intel i7 7700k, as ARM architecture would be the one incompatible with Windows 10. I called Microsoft and let them know about this, but they said that the i7-7700k is indeed incompatible and that Intel is saying the wrong information because their support is not knowledgeable about chipset design. I'm not sure whose right, but I do know that the processor box itself supports Windows 7, 8, 8.1, or 10. There must be confusion between the designers of the box or Microsoft employees.

Frankly, I don't want to upgrade to Windows 10 because all the times I upgraded I experienced at least 3 different bugs and annoyances, not to mention that I don't like this "Store" or "MSN" or the new "Start" screen, especially with its significantly lacking search functionality.

I kindly appreciate anyones help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58265/discussion-on-question-by-classesandobjects-how-can-i-stop-windows-from-providin).